# How to get all of the pages in a category and their summary on MediaWiki API

Tags: json, rest, mediawiki

I'm studying MediaWiki API. I wanted to get all of the pages in Programming_languages category and their summary,so I tried this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtype=page&gcmlimit=max&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&gcmtitle=Category:Programming_languages

But I got not all of data of the pages, and some data I could get don't have the summary. I couldn't solve this problem. How do I get data accurately?

Comment: Perhaps I could all of the pages. But I couldn't still get all summary...

Comment: As per [api](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts), there is a limit of 20 extracts. If you need extracts for each page, first query the page titles and then query for extract for each page title.

Comment: Thanks. I could get all of the summary by using "for" instead. I had better be careful not to give too many requests...

Comment: I did not understand  your use of 'for'.  You can get summaries for all by changing gcmlimit to 20 instead of 'max'.